SOBRE EL GRANGERTEST EN R STUDIO
ME APARECE ESTO AL EJECUTAR EL GRANGERTEST
 grangertest(DPRECIO.APP.ts~VOL.APP.ts,order(1))

Error en model.frame.default(mt, data = data):
'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list
COMO LO PUEDO SOLUCIONAR??

Según la documentación:

Cuando usas una formula, en tu caso DPRECIO.APP.ts~VOL.APP es condición obligatoria pasar por el segundo parámetro (data) un data.frame, un environment o una list, en tu ejemplo estas pasando order(1) que no es ninguno de los ojetos antes mencionado. La otra forma de usar la función es, pasando, dos parametros x e y que representan series bivariadas y univariadas. Se me ocurre que lo que buscas es más bien hacer algo así:
grangertest(DPRECIO.APP.ts, VOL.APP.ts, order(1))

Para más info
